# How to remove leading and trailing underscores but not the ones which are between two words?

Tags: python, regex

How to write a regex expression for python which removes leading and trailing underscore but not the ones in between two words?

Eg:

input: `_word`
output: `word`

input: `word_`
output: `word`

input: `word_word`
output: `word_word`

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Use `strip()`. If you have to use regex, you may replace `^_+|_+$` with an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strip(char)` returns a new string after removing any leading and trailing `char` from string.

```
x = '_hello_word_'
x = x.strip('_')
print(x)
```

output:

```
hello_word
```